# Construct mutable string from hash iteration

Tags: puppet

I'm stuck on the following puppet code from days, can you please give me an hand?

In hiera I have the following structure:

```
my_list::servers:
  server1.subnet.env.com:
    id: 0
  server2.subnet.env.com:
    id: 1
  server3.subnet.env.com:
    id: 2
  server4.subnet.env.com:
    id: 3
```

Where the various `server1..n` (n=>2) are the FQDN of the servers in the specific environment. The ID is always in order, but starting from 0.

I need to create a string that contains a comma separated list of string as `broker-${id}-check`, where id is different from the FQDN of the server where I'm running puppet, so for example if I'm running the script on `server2.subnet.env.com` the string should be `broker-0-check,broker-2-check,broker-3-check`. If I'm running on `server1.subnet.env.com` it will be `broker-1-check,broker-2-check,broker-3-check`, etc..

My last tentative is:

```
$servers_list = hiera('my_list::servers',  {"${::fqdn}" => {'id' => 0 } })
$list_broker=''
$servers_list.each |$key, $value| {
  if $key != $::fqdn {
    $list_broker="${list_broker},broker-${value['id']}-check"
  }
}
notify {"******* ${list_broker}": }
```

but `list_broker` is still empty and then I will have to fix the leading comma.

Is there a better way to do that?

I'm using Puppet 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that although Puppet has an iteration feature, it doesn't allow the reassignment of variables ([ref](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_variables.html#no-reassignment)).

For this reason, Puppet has a lot of functional programming features that allow you to solve problems like this without needing to reassign variables.

This works (Puppet < 5.5), where `join()` comes from stdlib:

```
$list_broker = join(
  $servers_list
    .filter |$key, $value| { $key != $::fqdn }
    .map    |$key, $value| { "broker-${value['id']}-check" },
  ','
)
```

Or in Puppet >= 5.5 (as suggested in comments), where the join command is built-in, the join can be chained too:

```
$list_broker = $servers_list
  .filter |$key, $value| { $key != $::fqdn }
  .map    |$key, $value| { "broker-${value['id']}-check" }
  .join(',')
```

If you'd prefer it in more steps:

```
$filtered = $servers_list.filter |$key, $value| { $key != $::fqdn } 
$mapped = $filtered.map |$key, $value| { "broker-${value['id']}-check" }
$list_broker = join($mapped, ',')
```

Explanation:

- The **`filter`** function selects elements from an Array or Hash on the basis of some criteria.
- The **`map`** function performs a transformation on all elements of an Array or Hash and returns an Array of transformed data.
- The **`join`** function (which prior to Puppet 5.5 comes from stdlib) joins an array of strings.

Comment: Clever chain; just curious: can you also chain a `.join` on the versions where it is an intrinsic function? I would assume yes.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yep, I just tested it and updated the answer.

Comment: Nice one; I just have this visual preference for method chaining so that gets me excited that this is now valid syntax in modern Puppet.